# How to validate email if and only if it is not empty with JOI

Tags: node.js, joi

I have a simple JOI (14.3.1) validation for `email` in user table:

```
email: Joi.string()
        .email(),
```

But this validation implicitly require email NOT empty which is not the case here and throws out error when email is empty. I just want to check the email format if and only if it is not empty. How can I do that with JOI?

Comment: Have you read this https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/482 ?

Comment: `email: Joi.string().email().optional()` is what you looking for?

Comment: `string().allow("").optional()` works